# AngularJS $http post sending JSON.stringify object which cause errors

Tags: jquery, json, angularjs

I am sending json request the request data is below give which gaves errors.

Example  :

```
ShippingAddress: "{"title":"sdasTEs","name":"dsd","address_line_1":"sda","city":"ads","email":"test@test.com","phone":8788797789797}"
amount: undefined
apptab_id: "17866"
fan_id: undefined
items: undefined
location_id: "771"
mobapp_id: "930"
ordertype: 2
special_instruction: "sadsa"
transaction_id: 0
transaction_type: 0
```

It Should be like

```
ShippingAddress: '{"title":"sdasTEs","name":"dsd","address_line_1":"sda","city":"ads","email":"test@test.com","phone":8788797789797}'
amount: undefined
apptab_id: "17866"
fan_id: undefined
items: undefined
location_id: "771"
mobapp_id: "930"
ordertype: 2
special_instruction: "sadsa"
transaction_id: 0
transaction_type: 0
```

Double quotes are casueing problems.

Comment: How are you sending data?

Comment: The above is the data i am sending and  $http.post('url', postData);

Comment: var postData = new Object();
            postData.ShippingAddress = $.cookie(shippingCookieName);
            postData.apptab_id = $.cookie('apptab_id');
            postData.fan_id = $.cookie('fan_id');
            postData.location_id = $.cookie('location_id');
            postData.mobapp_id = app_id;
            postData.ordertype = 2;
            postData.special_instruction = si;
            postData.transaction_id = 0;
            postData.transaction_type = 0;
            postData.items = $.cookie('cart');